# Example of a function $h$ which its Hardy-Littlewood maximal function $h^*$ is finite but unbounded

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I'm trying to solve the following problem from Axler's *Measure, Integration & Real Analysis*:

> Give an example of a Borel measurable function $h:\mathbb{R} \to [0,\infty)$ such that $h^*(b)<\infty$ for all $b\in \mathbb{R}$ but $\sup \{h^*(b):b\in\mathbb{R}\} = \infty.$

Here $h^*$ is the Hardy-Littlewood maximal function of $h$ which is defined as follows:
$$h^*(b)=\sup_{t>0}\frac{1}{2t}\int_{b-t}^{b+t}\lvert h \rvert.$$

My first guess was $f(x)=\lvert x\rvert$ since it seems to have the property everywhere but it fails at $0$. Now I think such a function could be the answer:
$$\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}(i+1)\chi_{[i^2,i^2+1]}$$
where $\chi_{[a,b]}$ is the characteristic function of $[a,b]$.

But I'm not sure that this function is a Borel measurable one and if it is, I don't know how prove or disprove that this is the answer.

Any help is appreciated.